# if condition inside element created with jquery not working

Tags: jquery

I want to create a html element with jquery with if condition, I tried the
 following but it wont work

```
 var abc = $('<tr><td>something</td>' +
     '</tr>'+
     if( a==0 ) { +
     '<tr><td class="coordinate" colspan="2">Current Location</td><td      class="chain">Chain Location</td></tr>' +
    }
 );
```

Comment: by *wont work* what do it mean?

Comment: you can't use condition in var use it like this

var  ad = $('<tr><td>something</td>');
var bd  = $(''<tr><td class="coordinate" colspan="2">Current Location</td><td      class="chain">Chain Location</td></tr>'');

if( a==0 ) { ad + bd }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `if` inside string. However, you can use [ternary operator `? :`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
var abc = $('<tr><td>something</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    (a === 0 ? '<tr><td class="coordinate" colspan="2">Current Location</td><td class="chain">Chain Location</td></tr>' : ''));
```

This is same as

```
if (a === 0) {
    string += 'Soemstring';
} else {
    string += ''; // i.e. add nothing
}
```

but, can be used inside string.

Answer (score 1):

You can rather use [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var abc = $('<tr><td>something</td>' +
         '</tr>'+
          (a == 0 ? '<tr><td class="coordinate" colspan="2">Current Location</td><tdclass="chain">Chain Location</td></tr>': '' )) ;
```

Comment: Try this in console: `'<tr><td>something</td>' +
         '</tr>'+
          false ? '<tr><td class="coordinate" colspan="2">Current Location</td><tdclass="chain">Chain Location</td></tr>': ''`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var strToappend = '';
    if( a==0 ) {  
      strToappend += '<tr><td class="coordinate" colspan="2">Current Location</td><td class="chain">Chain Location</td></tr>';
    }
    var abc = '<tr><td>something</td>' + '</tr>' + strToappend;
    alert(abc)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var abc = '<tr><td>something</td></tr>';
    if( a==0 ) {
        abc += '<tr><td class="coordinate" colspan="2">Current Location</td><td class="chain">Chain Location</td></tr>';
    }
```

Tri it!